# Rails missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, authentication, controller, action

I get this when I try and run my view:

```
Missing template application/login with {:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en], :handlers=>[:coffee, :erb, :builder]}. Searched in: * "/home/carladessi/Goods In Final/app/views"
```

in my controller I have:

```
def login

  # respond_to do |format|
  # format.html

end
```

and in my routes I have:

```
match "/login/", :controller => 'application',  :action => 'login'
```

I'm guessing I need to put something else in the controller I just don't know what.. sorry if this is a really blatant question!

Comment: Do you have the login.html.erb template in your view/application directory?

Comment: Where's your view? Also, the application controller is meant to be the parent of all the other controllers in your app. You don't usually define actions there.

Comment: yes i did, but i restarted my server and now it works. thank you anyway :) !

Comment: As a side note, `ApplicationController` is not intended to hold actions but to act as abstract controller. Otherwise, all your future controllers will inherit the `login` action (since by default all controller inherits from `ApplicationController`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Restarted the server and it works fine !

Answer (score 3):

It is not really conventional Rails to render views from the `application_controller`.

However, what is happening is Rails is looking for an actual template or view to be here:

```
RAILS_ROOT/app/views/application/login.html.erb
```

What you can do is **add**/**create** that template at the above path. Or you can redirect to another controller (which exists and does render an actual template).